# Datatables: Pagination current page not disabled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using bootstrap pagination with datatables

If I am in page number 4 and then click on button with number 4 then the page refreshes.
I display 100 records per page and it causes load on the server. But, "Previous" and "Next" buttons are disabled.   I want to also disable button with same number as the page I'm in (in this case, button for page 4)

[view this image](http://picpaste.com/download-aArTC1PS.png)

Comment: I tried to improve the text with what I understood. Please rollback my edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'm not really into using bootstrap so I don't know if bootstrap users could answer your question with the posted information. You might want to share relevant piece(s) of code.

Comment: hi @madth3! i found solution change file db_bootstrap.js

Comment: You should create an answer of your own and mark it as accepted, instead of the edition in your post. I'd recommend reading the page in [help] if you plan on keep using Stac kOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi everyone use following changes...

edit db_bootstrap.js line no:-81

```
            for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                    .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                    .bind('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        Settings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                });
```

use this...

```
            for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="javascript:void(0);">'+j+'</a></li>')
                    .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                    .bind('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
                        {
                            oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                            fnDraw( oSettings );
                        }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What I understand is the following:

1. You want to disable Next and Prev
2. When a user clicks on a page number the page should be refreshed.
3. You are using this in conjuction with Datatables.

For point 1 refer to the [Controlling the Presence of a Page item](http://bootstrappaginator.org/#controlling-the-presence-of-page-item) to understand how you can control the rendering of a page item.

Since, you are using the paginator in conjuction with Datatables, you would want to trigger the `fnDraw()` of the Datatable within the `onPageClicked` event handler. Refer to the documentation of [onPageClicked](http://bootstrappaginator.org/#page-clicked-event).

Let me know if this helps